# Find the component form, magnitude, and angle of forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

> Two teenagers are pulling on ropes attached to a tree. The angle between the ropes is 30.0°30.0° . David pulls with a force of 400.0 N and Stephanie pulls with a force of 300.0 N.
>
> (a) Find the component form of the net force.
>
> (b) Find the magnitude of the resultant (net) force on the tree and the angle it makes with David’s rope.

I'm a bit confused by this question. my first instinct was to make a right triangle, with Stephanie's force as the horizontal force and David's as the angled force. Stephanie's force would be 300i + 0j, and David's force would be 400cos30i + 400sin30j = 346.41i + 200j. After adding these together, you get the net component force as 646.41i + 200j.

However, if I put Stephanie's force as the angled force and David's as the horizontal, I would get David: 400i + 0j and Stephanie: 259.8i + 150j, and the net component force would be 659.8i + 150j. When I searched it up, I found that the latter answer was correct. Why do I get different answers? Why would the second one be correct, even though the question never says who would create the angle? Am I missing something with the question?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes!  Even if the question is in some sense *elementary*, it is still not "homework-like" because it is *explicitly* asking about the *conceptual* understanding of why you would do one thing and not another. Sure, this is really just a question about how to add vectors, or perhaps about different choices of *coordinate systems* (which makes it even more subtle!), but it is at its heart a conceptual question and not a homework-like question.

Comment: Without going through the details, it is likely that *both* expressions are correct!  By choosing one or the other to "be the angled force", you are making a choice of different *coordinate systems*!  You should draw a free-body diagram for the tree first, drawing the force arrows on the diagram, and then draw a set of *coordinate axes* (i.e., $x$ and $y$ axes).  The set of coordinate axes is *your choice*, and you can choose to line one axis up with either one or the other of the forces, in which case you'll get different answers. Just show the picture, work, and that should be it!

Comment: Voting to reopen as this is a conceptual question not a check-my-work question. And the conceptual answer is that both answers are correct, they are just stated relative to different orientations of the co-ordinate axes.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are correct - they are just stated relative to different orientations of the co-ordinate axes. We have

$\sqrt{646.41^2 +200^2} = 676.64
\\ \sqrt{659.8^2 + 150^2} = 676.64$

so the magnitude of the net force is the same for both answers, as we expect.